# How do I access google map if I put google map api into a frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I put google map v3 api into a frame/iframe

Then obviously if I still create a map instance using:

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(...)
```

would be wrong.

Then is it possible to create map in the parent window, without loading the api again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this discussion (Part 39 Communicating between iframes)](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/iframes.htm) of using maps in frames, it is from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, but the concepts apply to v3.